# C++ Member Initialization List / Creating Objects In A Class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, sfml

I'm having trouble getting my code to work. I'm pretty new to C++, but basically what I am trying to do is create objects of one class inside another.

I have read through a lot of things to try and get this to work but there's obviously some important step I have completely missed.

Basically calling `MainWindow.load()` should create the objects and `MainWindow.loop()` should return them. For context, in the final project; `MainWindow.load()` would set the textures (which only needs to be done once) whilst `MainWindow.loop()` would draw them continuously.

I would be grateful if you could take a look at my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class objects
{
private:
    int n;
public:
    void create (int);
    int output ();
};

void objects::create(int inputn)
{
    n = inputn;
}

int objects::output()
{
    return n;
}

class mainwindow
{
private:
    objects value1;
    objects value2;

public:
    void load();
    void loop();
};

void mainwindow::load()
{
    mainwindow() :  value1.create(56),
                    value2.create(72){}
}

void mainwindow::loop()
{
    std::cout << value1.output() << "\n";
    std::cout << value2.output() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    mainwindow MainWindow;
    MainWindow.load();

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Loop " << i << ":\n";
        MainWindow.loop();
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: A constructor initialization list can only be used in a constructor.

Comment: what you named "create method" should be a constructor. That's what ppl invented ctors for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create Object like this:

```
void mainwindow::load()
{
    value1.create(56);
    value2.create(72);
}
```

Or you can do it in the constructor without using load function:

```
mainwindow::mainwindow()
    :value1(56),
    value2(72)
{
}
```

in this case you need to write a constructor of objects

```
objects::objects(int arg = 0)
    :n(arg)
{
}
```

Comment: Wow great, I got both solutions working, thanks so much for your help! I think originally I must have read about both of those methods but didn't understand them well enough to get it working, so I slapped them both together into a coding mess!